# Loop Through List of Objects until condition is met, then set value of subsequent objects until the condition is met again

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a list of ItemForSale():

```
public class ItemForSale(){

public string Name {get;set;}
public bool OnSale {get;set;}
public int price {get;set;}
}
```

I have a sale price: (Will be decided by the user)

```
public int SalePrice {get;set;}
```

I need to loop through a list of these ItemForSale object.

If an Object is OnSale, then foreach object in the list subsequently, set price to SalePrice.

UNTIL the next ItemForSale.OnSale = true.

The process continues until all items in the list have a price.

This question is a very specific case and I have tried to think of the best way to ask it. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Have you looked at `SkipWhile()` and `TakeWhile()` in `Linq`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into those.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            List<ItemForSale> items = new List<ItemForSale>() {
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "abc", OnSale = true},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "def", OnSale = false },
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "ghi", OnSale = false},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "jkl", OnSale = true},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "mno", OnSale = false},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "pqr", OnSale = true},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "stu", OnSale = false},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "vwx", OnSale = true},
                new ItemForSale() { Name = "yz", OnSale = true}
            };

            List<List<ItemForSale>> groups = new List<List<ItemForSale>>();

            List<ItemForSale> group = null;

            foreach (ItemForSale item in items)
            {
                if (item.OnSale)
                {
                    group = new List<ItemForSale>();
                    group.Add(item);
                    groups.Add(group);
                }
                else
                {
                    group.Add(item);
                }
            }
```